# Beginner Programmer - Whether to start with ES5 or ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, smalltalk, ecmascript-5

I'm stepping onto the path of coding, for web services (full stack), after being a generalist in IT ops for many years. Ruby, Python, C# and JavaScript are interesting and Launch School looks like it has an excellent approach and curriculum for learning full stack, starting with Ruby on the back-end.

**What about C# and .net Core?**

However, a friend recently got me interested in C#, which is apparently a beautiful language to work with. The release of .net Core last month made this even more attractive. However, it's not a bad idea to start simple and to learn to program first and, unfortunately, C# is inseparable from .net. All the code examples appear to have .net throughout and maybe this makes it not so good for beginners to learn programming concepts.

The structure and strict typing of C# is attractive to me, but so is the 'simplicity' of Ruby and other dynamic languages. Ruby's OOP and the opinionatedness of the language is also attractive. Actually, there appear to be compelling reasons for each language.

**On to JavaScript**

So, continuing research shows that there is a strong case for JavaScript as a great first language, which will extend into many areas (web front and back end, DevOps, etc) and create, as Jeffrey Snover puts it, '[a virtuous cycle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/05/18/the-virtuous-cycle-net-developers-using-powershell/)'.

JavaScript looks good, too. It seems to be less verbose than C#. However, it has the disadvantage of not having C#'s strict typing, nor Ruby's opinionatedness, to help the programmer write better code. It's so loose. ES6 and TypeScript go a way towards resolving this problem and initially I wanted to just learn TypeScript. But, I'm a fundamentalist and so this just doesn't feel like the right way to go.

**Possible path**

This leads me to a path more or less based on:

1. learn to code, using ES5 (lots of available resources starting
   with Eloquent JavaScript, adding Speaking JavaScript, JavaScript:The Good Parts, etc);
2. add Smalltalk into the mix, as this sounds like a great baseline and is, by all accounts, a beautiful, simple/direct language with a pure OOP focus;
3. learn CSS and HTML, JSON, ReST;
4. learn TypeScript, ES6 once I am comfortable with ES5, including having avoided many of its pitfalls;
5. learn Node.js, and other JS variants, as required;
6. add frameworks, as required.

Anyway, JavaScript makes sense for full-stack, 'everything' web services. Great to learn a non-Microsoft stack, too.

Thanks,
nick

**EDIT:**

I have listened to a **[podcast](https://javascriptair.com/episodes/2015-12-16/)**, in which Kyle Simpson, Ashley Williams, et al, are talking about beginners using JavaScript to learn programming concepts. And, they are praising the lack of abstractions and sugar in ES5 and comparing this with the introduction of abstractions in ES6, some of which obscure aspects of the language from beginners.

In the context of ES6 making it harder for beginners they seem to point pretty strongly at Classes and that the implementation appears to be an odd fit for the language. But, they also mention how awesome Destructuring is and how this makes it easier to learn. It's an interesting discussion.

Ashley also gave a talk at jsconf2015 (link on the page linked to above) in which she looks at ES6 in the context of using it to learn programming concepts.

Comment: Great. So what is the question? Good chance it will be totally off topic anyway.

Comment: Node.js is not a JS variant. Node.js is an environment where JS runs in. The capability of JS is define with the ECMAScript Standard (ES). Everything that is beyond the language itself is about APIs and Framework.

Comment: How did Smalltalk creep into this discussion? What are you going to use it for, and how?

Comment: @JulienBernu I put a bit more in that original post for context, but the primary question is: 'should I learn programming with ES5 or ES6?'

Comment: @t.niese thanks for that correction. I knew that node.js wasn't a framework but was unclear of what the distinction is between it and native JavaScript.

Comment: @torazaburo haha, yeah, I thought that might throw things a bit, but it is a significant factor in my learning to code and figured that it might influence a recommendation. It is incredible just how often Smalltalk is mentioned in comparison to modern languages, and invariably, the programmer that mentions it talks about their love for it. It seems that learning it from the start is much more than an academic notion.

Comment: You can compare Node.js with Chrome, FireFox, IE, Opera, ... it is an application/enviroment in which the JavaScript code is evaluated and executed. Browsers have build in APIs for DOM manipulation and display, Node.js has build in API for file access, networking, ... .  But the JavaScript language is defined by the ECMAScript standard and is the same for all.

Comment: **@t.niese** So, my takeaway is that node.js provides users with a set of APIs to access files, network services, and other back-end services?... ah, ok, I read the Wikipedia article which adds to your answer nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is a great language but it is also very confusing and there is a lot of bad articles out there. Unlike the other answer, I suggest you learn ES5 first because all the books you have mentioned are written in ES5. You don't want to confuse yourself with arrow syntax and other syntactic sugar. You will also appreciate ES6 more once you suffer a bit with ES5 but I believe that is the necessary part of learning. It would also give you a better perspective on to why these new features where added to ES6.

When it comes to learning Javascript, my opinion is to choose multiple sources, like videos, following the right people on twitter, listening to podcasts, articles etc. Here is a good place to guide you on your journey: http://jstherightway.org/

The books you have mentioned are great but I would add two more books to it. Javascript the definitive guide and you don't know JS.

I have read Eloquent JS, The Definitive Guide and Javascript the good parts but I felt that I truly started to grasp JS after I read "You don't know JS - by Kyle Simpson" https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

I highly suggest his video course "Advanced Javascript for serious Programmers". It really opened my eyes to the javascript paradigm.

Don't jump on frameworks because you will wasted a lot of time on configuration instead of learning actual javascript.

Comment: **@yasin** thanks very much. You and **@RoboRobok** have recommended very different approaches. I guess the answer to my question is very dependent on the degree of adoption of ES6 and availability of learning materials.

Comment: **@yasin**  Thanks for suggesting the book and video series by Kyle Simpson, and pointing out 'JS the right way'.

Answer (score 2):

At the time you are proficient in JavaScript, ES6 will most likely be fully supported. I would go straight to ES6. Then, I would learn JavaScript framework, like [Angular 2](https://angular.io/).

ES6 includes almost all features of ES5, they are not entirely different. There is a [very good ES6 description](http://es6-features.org/#Constants) available.

Comment: If he is going to learn Angular2, then he will almost certainly need to learn TypeScript. Also, ES6 includes **all** features of ES5, not just "almost all".

Comment: Yes! ES6 all the way. It was harder for me to switch from 5 to 6 because of all the new features, but a) you don't have to use them and b) when you do get comfortable using them, they help rather than obstruct!

Comment: @torazaburo Angular 2 goes without TypeScript too. Plus, some features - or rather behaviors - of ES5 were deprecated, that's why I said "almost all".

Comment: Sure, you can either use Angular2 with TypeScript, or you can stick pins in your eye. Your choice.

Comment: @torazaburo Having used neither Angular or TS, why do I need to learn Typescript to make learning Angular 2 easier?

Comment: @torazaburo Angular 2 goes well with pure JavaScript and introduces some improvements if you decide to use TypeScript or Dart. I don't think it's putting anything to your eye :)

Comment: @Abdul Not easier, but better. TypeScript offers features to make your code easier to debug and maintain, but learning will be actually harder. Once you are proficient, it will become easier to create applications with it though.

Comment: But yeah, Stack Overflow doesn't like such types questions, so maybe let's move to chat if you are still in doubt.

Comment: @RoboRobok your response is the main reason for my question. I watched Axel Rauschmayer cover ES6 in [this two-part video taken of a talk in 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fg3bEZIcnUw) and, on the face of it, learning how to program by using ES6 would be an easy choice. But, Yasin also raises a really good point.

Comment: **@torazaburo** yes, I agree. I would learn TypeScript, either before or during Angular 2 (probably beforehand, as mentioned in 4. Erich Gamma talks about TypeScript in this video [about the making of Visual Studio Code](https://www.thoughtworks.com/talks/building-a-cross-platform-development-tool-using-javascript) and although the size of the project makes it an obvious choice, there seems to be a benefit for everyone working on more than just snippets.

Comment: **@sg.cc** I agree, ES6 is a very logical starting point.

Answer (score 2):

When you see :

## ES5

```
[{lb:'Email',val:'ab@kg.co.sa'}].map(function(e){
      return '<div><label>'+e.lb+'</label>'+'<input value="'+e.val+'" />'+'</div>'
             
})
```

Can be written in **ES6** :

```
[{lb:'Email',val:'ab@kg.co.sa'}].map(({lb,val})=>`<div><label>${lb}</label> <input value="${val}" /></div>`)
```

You will take the decision by yourself.

#### ==> The elegance & the productivity are with **ES6**.

Comment: `${l}` and `${v}` appear `undefined` at result at es6 version

Comment: sorry : i will update now , ,anyway, check this demo : https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/muvzaohy/4/

Comment: **@AbdennourTOUMI** thanks. I agree, ES6 is clearly superior and, no doubt, easier to learn.